# emacs preview duplicate lines before removing

Tags: emacs, duplicates, highlighting

Context: I'm working with a large text file that is almost excel-like and I'm adding/editing entries. It is a shared file so others can have already edited the file.

I'm working with emacs and I found that they added the command delete-duplicate-lines. This command seems great for pruning extra entries, but it would be nice to know which lines were duplicates (i.e. already existed in the file) so that I would know which entries had already been added. Is there a command that is similar to delete-duplicate-lines, but only points out which lines are duplicates without removing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use command **`hlt-highlight-line-dups-region`** from the [Highlight](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) library, to highlight all sets of duplicate lines in the region or (if no active region) in the buffer.

By default, leading and trailing whitespace are ignored
when checking for duplicates, but this is controlled by option
`hlt-line-dups-ignore-regexp`.  And with a prefix arg the behavior
effectively acts opposite to the value of that option.  So if the
option says not to ignore whitespace and you use a prefix arg then
whitespace is ignored, and vice versa.

You can also control the colors/faces used to highlight each set of duplicates.

Comment: Oh wow, this worked pretty well, thanks! Side note though; Right now, I have the highlight.el file in the emacs/share/emacs/24.5/site-lisp folder, and in order to use the highlight library, I have to load it with M-x load-library, type "highlight" as the library to load, and then call hlt-highlight-line-dups-region. Is there an easier way to do this? I'm using Windows and my copy of emacs doesn't seems to have the .emacs file (I've turned on hidden files, but no dice).

Comment: `C-x C-f ~/.emacs`, then add whatever you want to the file, and save it. Put `highlight.el` (and/or `highlight.elc` if you byte-compile the `.el`, which I recommend) in a directory that you add to your `load-path` (`(add-to-list 'load-path THAT-DIRECTORY)`). And then add `(require 'highlight)` to your init file (`~/.emacs`). See the Emacs manual, node [Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). Do **not** mess with folder `site-lisp`.